# Php Alphabet Loop

Tags: php

```
<?php
$string = 'hey';

foreach (range('a', 'z') as $i) {
    if ($string == '$i') {
        echo $i;
    }
}
?>
```

Why is this not working? please tell me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: yeah, what's not working ? Youre comparing each letter of the alphabet to "hey" so it's normal that nothing happens.

Answer (score 26):

You have two problems in your code.

First, single-quotes strings (`'`) behave differently than double-quotes string (`"`). When using single-quotes strings, escape sequences (other than `\'` and `\\`) are not interpreted and variable are not expended. This can be fixed as such (removing the quotes, or changing them to double-quotes):

```
$string = 'hey';

foreach(range('a','z') as $i) {
  if($string == $i) {
    echo $i;
  }
}
```

> [PHP Documentation: Strings](http://php.net/types.string)

---

Secondly, your condition will never evaluate to `TRUE` as `'hey'` is never equal to a single letter of the alphabet. To evaluate if the letter is in the word, you can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
$string = 'hey';

foreach(range('a','z') as $i) {
  if(strpos($string, $i) !== FALSE) {
    echo $i;
  }
}
```

The `!== FALSE` is important in this case as [`0` also evaluates to `FALSE`](http://php.net/types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting). This means that if you would remove the `!== FALSE`, your first character would not be outputted.

> [PHP Documentation: `strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos)
>   [PHP Documentation: Converting to boolean](http://php.net/types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting)
>   [PHP Documentation: Comparison Operators](http://php.net/operators.comparison)

Answer (score 3):

It is but you aren't seeing anything because:

```
'hey' != '$i'
```

Also if your $i wasn't in single quotes (making it's value '$i' literally)

```
'hey' != 'a';
'hey' != 'b';
'hey' != 'c';
...
'hey' != 'z';
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just do it by string increment:

```
$x = 'A';
for($i=0; $i < 30; $i++){ 
  echo $x++;
  echo "; "; 
}
```

gives

```
A; B; C; D; E; F; G; H; I; J; K; L; M; N; O; P; Q; R; S; T; U; V; W; X; Y; Z; AA; AB; AC; AD;
```

Answer (score -1):

In place of testing == have a look on the [strspn()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php) function